# i cannot install Unity Modules, how do i do it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to install a new version of unity from unity hub but when i try to dowload it, it does not fully complete the download bar.[image]

Later i proceed downloading the editor for a manual instalation, i finally install the version i wanted to but in the installer does not show the aditional modules to build the games, i also try adding this modules in unity hub but once again the modules never finished to charge.

[image]

I need to install the additional modules but i do not find any answer to my problem

Comment: What additional modules? Do you mean packages? Those are done inside the editor on a per-project basis. If you can name the modules you want we can probably help.

Comment: Start by upgrading your hub to the latest version. Your version looks archaic which is probably the issue.

Comment: If possible, update the Unity Hub to the latest version using the button at the top (Hub  3.2.0 Available). This may be a bug which has been already patched, only way to know is to update.

Comment: @CreativeCoder exactly, and if it doesn't work but he still wishes to keep an outdated hub, he can always restore his computer to before the update.

Comment: I  just now upgraded the unity hub but eventhoug the unity 2021.3.6f1 is a LTS version when i try to add some modules a new window pup up with this message: Unity 2021.3.6f1 is no longer available from the Hub. For a better experience, we recommend the latest LTS (Long-Term Support) version. You can find all Editor versions in the Installs